# How to retrieve the child element of a tag with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to retrieve only the `<a>` child of `<b>` from my xml file with an xslt no matter what it is above

However, I get all the elements  that are in my xml (and not just what interests me).
For example, if I have:

```
<x> 
   <z>
      <b>
         <a>my element </a>
      </b>
  </z>
</x>
```

or just :

```
<x> 
    <b>
       <a>my element </a>
    </b>
</x>
```

I would like to recover :my element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">



        <xsl:output method="text"/>
           <xsl:template match="x">
                <xsl:for-each select="b/a">
                     <xsl:value-of select="w" /> 
                </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it's  <xsl:value-of select="a" />

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to retrieve only the `<a>` child of `<b>` from my xml
>   file with an xslt no matter what it is above

You were close. Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="b/a">
        <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**: override the built-in rule for text nodes with empty template (no output). Just output what you want with a rule matching exactly that.

> However, I get all the elements that are in my xml

That sentence is odd because you are ussing the `text` output method...

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you don't know the structure of the input XML in advance. In any case:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="//a" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

will retrieve the value of the `a` element, no matter where it's located in the input XML document's hierarchy.

To limit this to `a` element that is a child of `b`, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//b/a" />
```